# Find $\frac{N_r}{D_r}$ for small $x$.

Tags: calculus

> Let 
>   $$N_r= (1-x)^{-\frac{5}{2}} + (16+8x)^{\frac{1}{2}}\quad\text{and}\quad
> D_r = (1+x)^{-\frac{1}{2}} + (2+x)^2.$$
>   Show that
>   $$\frac{N_r}{D_r} = 1 + \frac{23x^2}{40}+o(x^2).$$

On simplification I am not getting the RHS. Kindly help.

Comment: For $x=0$ both $N_r,D_r=5$ so the expression works.  You need to expand both to order $x^2$.  Please show what you have tried.

Comment: (1-x)^(-5/2) = 1+5x/2+ 35x^2/8   (16+8x)^(1/2) = 4+2x-x^2/8

Answer (score 0):

This is my work
\begin{gather}
(1-x)^{-\frac{5}{2}} = 1+\frac{5x}{2}+ \frac{35x^2}{8}\\
(16+8x)^\frac{1}{2}= 4+2x-\frac{x^2}{8}\\
(1+x)^{-\frac{1}{2}} = 1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{3x^2}{8}\\
(2+x)^2=x^2+4x+4
\end{gather}
On simplification
\begin{gather}
N_r = 5 + \frac{9x}{2} + \frac{17x^2}{4}  \\
D_r= 5+\frac{7x}{2}+\frac{11x^2}{8} \\
\frac{N_r}{D_r} = 1 +\frac{x}{5} + \frac{87x^2}{200}
\end{gather}

Comment: Can you please use MathJax or else your question will get downvoted.See it on META about how to write nathematically.

Comment: I submitted an edit for your formatting, is this what you intended to write?